# AWS Public WebServers to NOT directly reachable from Outside by their IPs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet, amazon-vpc

Since i'm totally not a Network Admin, i have no idea how to design it or even possible or not. I'm using AWS and EC2 instances. But now for some security reasons, i am told to use VPC and Private Subnets.

I don't have knowledge good enough but -

- Is it possible to put all my current public WEB SERVERS into a Private Network? The goal is to prevent the WEBSERVERS from the direct Public Reachability (using their Public IP) except by the Load-balancer in front of them.

So lets say i have 2 WEBSERVERS (load-balanced) for the site `www.example.com`:

- Web-A (202.1.2.3)
- Web-B (202.4.5.6)

That means currently those are reachable by their Public IPs.

- Then can i make those **not reachable by IPs** from Outside but still to serve the `www.example.com` to Public? (Is that what VPC + Private Subnets, for?)

I'm sorry for my confusion. Any suggestion on this please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you described is a good way to architect your VPC. Your web servers can be in private subnets  that access the Internet through a NAT server. Inbound connections from clients will be proxied by a load balancer, usually an ELB. So the flow looks like this:

```
Clients <=> Load Balancer/ELB (Public subnets) <=> Web/App Servers (Private subnets) <=> Database servers (private subnets)
```

In this architecture the load balancer listens on ports 80 and 443 and terminates SSL connections. The load balancer has a routable public IP address and sends traffic to the web servers on a port of your choosing, perhaps 8080. The web servers have only private addresses and are not publicly accessible.

I humbly submit a talk on VPC architecture I did recently. [See the slides here](https://speakerdeck.com/bwhaley/aws-design-patterns-at-anki).

Comment: You could also just deny all access to port 80 in web server security group except from the load balancer security group, this effectively restricts access from the greater internet to go through your load balancers, without the need for setting up a VPC, and the extra cost of the NAT box.

VPC is still a recommended way to go if you have the means to set it up and manage it though.